# Uploading multi images in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner in laravel.  I'm trying to submit a post with the option to upload multiple files if the user wants. I keep getting the error "Undefined variable: data." Where did I go wrong?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     //validate
     $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|min:10',
        'body'  => 'required|min:20',
        'filename' => 'nullable|max:2480',
        'filename.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'


    ]);   

    //store Image
    if($request->file('filename'))
    {        
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
        {
            $name=time().$image->getClientOriginalName();;
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
    }

    $post= new Post();
    $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->filename=json_encode($data);
    $post->save();

    return back()->withMessage('Post created successfully.');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it will be better to declare your array outside the foreach loop.

You can try something like this:

Outside your foreach loop.

```
$data = array();
```

Inside your foreach loop, try to populate the array like this:

```
array_push($data, $name);
```

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     //validate
     $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|min:10',
        'body'  => 'required|min:20',
        'filename' => 'nullable|max:2480',
        'filename.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'


    ]);   

   //Initialize an empty array
   $data = array();


    //store Image
    if($request->file('filename'))
    {        
        foreach($request->file('filename') as $image)
        {
            $name=time().$image->getClientOriginalName();;
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);

            //populate array here
            array_push($data, $name);
        }
    }

    $post= new Post();
    $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $post->title = $request->input('title');
    $post->body = $request->input('body');
    $post->filename=json_encode($data);
    $post->save();

    return back()->withMessage('Post created successfully.');

}
```